# Is there a way to select/highlight a Date Range/series using Delphi 10.3 FMX TCalendar (Or a similar component)?

Tags: firemonkey, date-range, delphi-10.3-rio

I am looking for a way to highlight a range of dates between a given start date and end date using a TCalendar in a Delphi 10.3 FMX application. It is for visual purposes as the client selects a start and end date in seperate TDateEdit components.

I have looked it up, but I can't seem to find anything that explains what I want to achieve. Does the TCalendar perhaps have a method that achieves this, or is there a possible work-around?

I hope that my question was clear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The TCalendar is a component that is setup with a model class, a component class, and a style class. There are multiple controls that work this way. I can write a lenghty answer about how all of this works, but when I first started exploring FMX I had to dig in this for myself and found een article by Yaroslavin Brovin about the topic. It's in Russian (some of it translated in not that well written English) so you have to use a translator if you aren't familiar with the language (such as me :)). Here is then [website](http://yaroslavbrovin.ru/tcalendar_with_highlight_days_based_on_default_tcalendar/)

Just thinking out loud here: What you can do is add a begin/end date prop to the model class en make your own derived style class where you can give the days you want to highlight your own preferred style through painting directly, or through styling via StyleBook.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I am fairly new with FMX, and I don't know much about the StyleBook. I will certainly explore further.
I'll give the article a read, thanks!